# My own accordion javascript does not work.

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

```
<div id="wrapDesktopNavBar">
        <ul class="desktopNavBar" id="accordion">

            <li>
                <form class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" required>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#home"  onclick="callthis()">Main Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#">Main category 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 1</a>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 2</a>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 3</a>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 4</a>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 5</a>
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">Sub Category 6</a>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#">Main Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#">Main category 4</a>
                <ul>...
```

This is my html and my javascript to get the sub categories to slide up:

```
  $("#accordion > li").on('click', function () {
      if (false == $(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
          $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
      }
      $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(300);
  });
```

but when i clicked the main category, the sub categories won't come out. it's supposed to slide out nicely like the jquery ui accordion. Please help. I'm not very sure why the sub categories are not showing.

Comment: Can you put this in jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: Is this selector right? `$('#accordion > ul')`

Comment: @SreekeshOkky  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-fiddle/loemajeogfdlphofpdfncpbbeoenmbpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/5MwA9/)**

```
$('.firstLevel').click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: If you want that the Sub Category appears by default just remove the css from my fiddle

Comment: Hi! thanks! it works fine. However, it only works when i placed the javascript at the end of my html page, it didnt work when i placed it in a separate js file. Why is that so?

Comment: Are you using jquery document.ready ? $(document).ready(function(){ //your code });